# Is it possible to do dynamic variables in ruby?

Tags: php, ruby

I can accomplish this dynamic nature in other ways, but it caused me to be curious.  Is there a similar mechanism to this in Ruby?

```
$varname = "hello";
$$varname = "world";
echo $hello;  //Output: world
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve something similar using `eval`

```
x = "myvar"
myvar = "hi"
eval(x) -> "hi"
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible only for instance variables (and class variables):

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @varname = :"@hello"
    instance_variable_set @varname, "world"
  end

  def greet
    puts instance_variable_get(@varname)
  end
end

MyClass.new.greet
#=> "world"
```

For local variables you have to use `eval`.

Comment: Is there an extra colon in there on line 3?

Comment: Yes, the colon is equivalent to calling to_sym on a string literal: convert it to a symbol.

Comment: IOW `:"abcdef" == "abcdef".to_sym == :abcdef`, and you can use interpolation too `:"#{klazz}_#{id}" == "#{klazz}_#{id}".to_sym`.